# Ao iniciar o eclipse apareceu um erro

Tags: eclipse

Ao iniciar o Eclipse apareceu esse erro:

> An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Por que apareceu esse erro?

Essas foram as mensagens de erro encontradas na pasta;

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-29 08:07:32.156
!MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer", thread "Thread[Worker-1,5,main]" timed out waiting (5049ms) for thread "Thread[Worker-4,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.6.2.20150902-0002 [550]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-1,5,main]" is proceeding but "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.m2e.jdt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.6.2.20150902-0002"; singleton:="true" [id=550] STARTED [STARTED]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3345)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3321)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2849)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1900)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3298)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2857)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.classpathdep.ClasspathDependencyUtil.getComponentClasspathDependencies(ClasspathDependencyUtil.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.classpathdep.ClasspathDependencyUtil.getComponentClasspathDependencies(ClasspathDependencyUtil.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getJavaClasspathReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getNonManifestRefs(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootUtil.hasConsumableReferences(SingleRootUtil.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootUtil.validateSingleRoot(SingleRootUtil.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootUtil.isSingleRoot(SingleRootUtil.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootExportParticipant.canOptimize(SingleRootExportParticipant.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.canOptimize(FlatVirtualComponent.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.cacheResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.getChildModules(FlatVirtualComponent.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.FlatComponentDeployable.getExportModelChildren(FlatComponentDeployable.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.FlatComponentDeployable.getModules(FlatComponentDeployable.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServer.getChildModules(TomcatServer.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getChildModules(Server.java:2637)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.visitModule(Server.java:3058)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.visit(Server.java:3039)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getAllModules(Server.java:1542)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServersView2$3.run(ServersView2.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-29 08:07:36.045
!MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer", thread "Thread[Worker-3,5,main]" timed out waiting (5000ms) for thread "Thread[Worker-4,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.6.2.20150902-0002 [550]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-3,5,main]" is proceeding but "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.m2e.jdt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.6.2.20150902-0002"; singleton:="true" [id=550] STARTED [STARTED]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3345)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:3321)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2849)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$10.run(JavaModelManager.java:2774)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2814)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1895)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaCore.java:4067)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-29 08:07:37.634
!MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathHelpers", thread "Thread[Worker-1,5,main]" timed out waiting (5001ms) for thread "Thread[Worker-4,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.6.2.20150902-0002 [550]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-1,5,main]" is proceeding but "org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathHelpers" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.m2e.jdt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.6.2.20150902-0002"; singleton:="true" [id=550] STARTED [STARTED]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2868)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1900)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3298)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2857)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.classpathdep.ClasspathDependencyUtil.getComponentClasspathDependencies(ClasspathDependencyUtil.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.classpathdep.ClasspathDependencyUtil.getComponentClasspathDependencies(ClasspathDependencyUtil.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getJavaClasspathReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getNonManifestRefs(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootUtil.hasConsumableReferences(SingleRootUtil.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootUtil.validateSingleRoot(SingleRootUtil.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootUtil.isSingleRoot(SingleRootUtil.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jst.common.internal.modulecore.SingleRootExportParticipant.canOptimize(SingleRootExportParticipant.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.canOptimize(FlatVirtualComponent.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.cacheResources(FlatVirtualComponent.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatVirtualComponent.getChildModules(FlatVirtualComponent.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.FlatComponentDeployable.getExportModelChildren(FlatComponentDeployable.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.FlatComponentDeployable.getModules(FlatComponentDeployable.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServer.getChildModules(TomcatServer.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getChildModules(Server.java:2637)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.visitModule(Server.java:3058)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.visit(Server.java:3039)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getAllModules(Server.java:1542)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServersView2$3.run(ServersView2.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2015-11-29 08:07:46.845
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2868)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$10.run(JavaModelManager.java:2774)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2812)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1895)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3298)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2857)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClasspathChange.generateDelta(ClasspathChange.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessor.java:2032)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessingState.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessingState.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1470)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2250)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$NotifyJob.run(NotificationManager.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-11-29 08:07:47.275
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2868)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$10.run(JavaModelManager.java:2774)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2814)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1895)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaCore.java:4067)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-11-29 08:07:49.388
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\mary'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Comment: Tentou excluir o workspace e criar um novo, conforme foi sugerido na resposta do @David ?

Comment: Não há nada a fazer. Espere o eclipse passar para poder usar o seu computador normalmente. </joke>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se o seu Workspace/.metadata /.log ou a exibição de erro para ter mais informações sobre o que isso realmente significa o NullPointerException.

Ou conforme [resposta para uma pergunta parecida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892790/eclipse-internal-error-while-initializing-java-tooling), exclua sua workspace existente e recrie adicionando seus projetos.

Comment: acabei de atualizar minha postagem, dá uma olhada e ver de pode me ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Tive esse mesmo problema. E a solução que serviu pra mim foi fechar todos os projetos e reabrir o que eu estava usando. Essa solução estava em um comentário da resposta mais votada do [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892790/eclipse-internal-error-while-initializing-java-tooling) que passaram acima.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tbm apagar todos os JARS que baixou via Maven, as vezes alguns deles corrompem e causam problema na abertura do eclipse, você pode apagalos indo direto na pasta M2.